# Selecting Random Result from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to randomly select results from mysql database with this code:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 4") or die(mysql_error());
```

I got an error message: **FUNCTION members.RANDOM does not exist**

Is there something I'm not adding or doing right here?

Thanks for your asistance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The function name you're looking for is [RAND()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand).

Answer (score 8):

You need `ORDER BY RAND()`

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL uses RAND() instead of RANDOM().

Answer (score 1):

Since it's MySQL, you need to use RAND() instead of RANDOM().

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good source of advice for efficiently retrieving random records from a table with MySQL.

http://www.dasprids.de/blog/2008/06/07/fetching-random-rows-of-mysql-efficiently

You might want to check it out.